# How to have 2 or more regular expressions with exclusive OR in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex to find an email `mailto:(.*)\"|(\S+@+\S*)|(.{1,40}@.{1,40})` on several HTML sources.

Having the string `Email: <u><a href="mailto:test@test.com">email me` the piece `mailto:(.*)\"` works great,

I would want it to stop there and return the value instead of continuing with the other expressions. Is there something like an XOR operator or a way to do this since I would have to add more pieces eventually?

I tried here: http://pythex.org/

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, I think the regex engine already does what you are talking about (assuming you are invoking it with `re.search` or something similar).  The resulting `Match` object (assuming there was a match) would contain only one captured substring.

Comment: If you use `search` or `findall` it will only return something for `.{1,40}@.{1,40}` and nothing for the remaining two. This is the issue I'm trying to deal with. 
`re.match` won't return anything for `re.match('mailto:(.*)\"', s)` being `s` the string sample I described above.

Answer (score 0):

Regex should do this naturally. To illustrate this point, one of the easy ways of matching a word with one exception is to precede your match with the exception and use an alternation.

For instance in my email program I need to sort all emails with the subject line `/labels?/` to another folder. However some of my contacts never learned how to spell (apparently) and I also sort `/lables?/` However I noticed that emails containing the subject line `Available` were also being picked up by this filter.

I could have done `/\blables?/` but preferred instead to catch `available` and handle it separately, so I did:

```
`/available|(lables?)|(labels?)/`
```

This alternation will match `available`, but only match and capture `lable`, `lables`, `label`, or `labels`.

Comment: Nice solution, however this does not illustrate the same situation I'm dealing with. Executing this: 
`>>> re.findall("mailto:(.*)\"", 'Email: <u><a href="mailto:test@test.com">email me')`
`['test@test.com']`
`>>> re.findall("mailto:(.*)\"|(\S+@+\S*)|(.{1,40}@.{1,40})", 'Email: <u><a href="mailto:test@test.com">email me')`
`[('', '', 'Email: <u><a href="mailto:test@test.com">email me')]`

but the second call should clean return the email, am I missing something?

Comment: @dnuske the second call finds a literal `@` and returns the 40 characters before and after it. Maybe instead you should be finding `href="mailto:` and grabbing everything until `"` ?

Comment: like this: `re.findall("href=\"mailto:(.*)\"|(\S+@+\S*)|(.{1,40}@.{1,40})", 'Email: <u><a href="mailto:test@test.com">email me')` returns the same: `[('', '', 'Email: <u><a href="mailto:test@test.com">email me')]`. I don't understand why it doesn't return `[('test@test.com', '', 'Email: <u><a href="mailto:test@test.com">email me')]`, actually I would like to just get `['test@test.com']`.

Comment: @dnuske the problem you're having is that your last alternation `.{1,40}@.{1,40}` begins matching well before the rest of your alternations, so it consumes the text and that's the match that returns. Is there some problem with doing `\S+@\S+?\.(?:com|net|org|etc....)`? That should catch most email addresses (although [wikipedia will show you](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses) that valid email addresses can be very strange indeed!)

Answer (score 0):

As Adam Smith said, *the problem you're having is that your last alternation `.{1,40}@.{1,40}` begins matching well before the rest of your alternations, so it consumes the text and that's the match that returns.*
To overcome this, you could modify the other partial patterns so that they match just as early, by prepending `.*?` e. g. `.*?mailto:(.*)\"|.*?(\S+@+\S*)|(.{1,40}@.{1,40})`.
Or, perhaps somewhat less convoluted, you could just search for one after the other:

```
string = 'Email: <u><a href="mailto:test@test.com">email me'
m = re.search('mailto:(.*)\"',     string) \
 or re.search('(\S+@+\S*)',        string) \
 or re.search('(.{1,40}@.{1,40})', string)
print(m.group(1))
```